# How do parse this XML feed in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I need to parse the following ridiculously formed XML feed in PHP. It is from a real estate company who didn't think to have a 'property type' node - instead they have an 'apartment' node for apartments, a 'house' node for houses etc. My problem is that I need to extract sub nodes of these in order to get 'bedrooms', 'sub_type' and other info (this is a very stripped down version of the original).

```
<properties>
<property>
    <general_info>
        <id>1</id>
    </general_info>
    <apartment>
        <sub_type>1</sub_type>
        <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>
    </apartment>
</property>
<property>
    <general_info>
        <id>2</id>
    </general_info>
    <house>
        <sub_type>3</sub_type>
        <bedrooms>5</bedrooms>
    </house>
</property>
<property>
    <general_info>
        <id>3</id>
    </general_info>
    <business>
        <sub_type>6</sub_type>
        <bedrooms>0</bedrooms>
    </business>
</property>
```

I'm using **simplexml_load_file** to 'grab' the feed and performing a foreach loop over the elements. After some research it looks like **xpath** would help, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the basics of my code:

```
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($XML_FILE_NAME);

foreach($xmlObject->property as $property)
{

    // Get Property sub-type
    $property_sub_types = $property->xpath('//sub_type');
    foreach($property_sub_types as $sub_type)
    {
        print_r($sub_type); // printing to screen for demo purposes
    }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting. Correct values, but shown 3 times instead of 1.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 1
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 3
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 6
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 1
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 3
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 6
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 1
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 3
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 6
)
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated. Oh, and before you ask, getting them to redo their feed is not an option.

Comment: what is the exact problem? the xpath expression is returning no results? is there a default namespace associated with the xml?

Comment: The XML doesn't include a default namespace unfortunately.

Comment: @KeithHall I've updated my question with the output I'm getting. Hope that is clearer now.

Comment: An XPath expression beginning `//` means "start at the root of the document, then find everything matching". To start at the current context, you need to use `.`, i.e. start with `.//`.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP - this definitely puts me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath  `//sub_type`  selects all sub_type elements in th whole document.
Change it to `.//sub_type` should help

Comment: Thanks to hr_117 and @IMSoP who appear to have come up with the answer to my issue at the same time. Adding that crucial dot solves the issue for me - thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Please find below code :
Are you exactly want to like this?


$xmlObject = simplexml_load_file("XML File Path");
//print_r($xmlObject);
foreach($xmlObject->property as $property)
{    
    foreach($property as $test){
        //print_r($test->sub_type);
        echo "Bedrooms:-" .$test->bedrooms."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
        echo "Sub Type:".$test->sub_type;
      //print_r($property->business->sub_type);
      echo "</br>";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gaurav-jariwala. This does output the correct data, but it also output "Bedrooms:-   Sub Type:" in addition to the correct data on every loop. How can we get around this?

Comment: Does not use xpaht but should do. +1